# Play Text Underline Animation when hovering over div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I recently found an Animation for text underlines, and have trouble to shoot it when hovering over the parent, parfe div.
It's not created by @Keyframes, that's why is so difficult.

I hope you guys can help me!

~ Felix

HTML File:

```
<div class="newsBox">
  <div class="titleBox">
    <a class="newsTitle" id="newsTitle">News</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS File:

```
.newsBox {
 padding-top: 5%;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
 background-color: rgba(154, 54, 67, 0.5);
}

.titleBox {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

  .newsTitle {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    font-style: italic;
   }

  .newsTitle::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   }

  .newsTitle:hover::before {
   visibility: visible;
   width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy! Just change the last part of your code to the parent.

```css
.newsbox:hover .newsTitle::before {
   visibility: visible;
   width: 100%;
}
```

So now if you hover over the `.newsbox`, the `.newsTitle::before` in there will get that new styling.

And if you want to get the effect when hovering over the `.titleBox` then just change it to

```css
.titleBox:hover .newsTitle::before {
   visibility: visible;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's really that easy! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you change The last part of the css code With the code below , you will reach your goal.

```
.newsBox:hover ::before {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
```

you added hover selector to the child of parent `.newstitle`, you must add to hover to parent `.newsBox`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Make sens too! Thanks mate (:

Comment: That would work to indeed, but I think it's cleaner to select the `.newsTitle::before` instead of all the `::before` that are in the `.newsBox`